# Deserializing 2D array of objects JSON to Java

Tags: java, arrays, json, deserialization, gson

I'm using GSON to deserialize my JSON string. It seems to choke when attempting to deserialize a 2D array of objects. Here's the bit:

```
{ .
  ..
  ...
  "states": [
            {"SPAWNINGPHASE": [{"name": "STATEA", "duration": 4}, {"name": "STATEB", "duration": 4}]},
            {"ALIVEPHASE": [{"name": "STATEA", "duration": 5}, {"name": "STATEB", "duration": 4}]}
            ]
}
```

The above is a part of a bigger JSON.
I get `Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT`
I've looked over my JSON, but I don't see where it's incorrect

```
Group g=gson.fromJson(configFile, Group.class);
```

That's what I use to start the read. Is this not enough to process the string for the 2D array?

In Group.class I tried both

```
public State[][] states;
```

and

```
public List<List<State>> states;
```

Everything else seems to deserialize fine.

Do I have to use this (below)?

```
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<Integer>>(){}.getType();
Collection<Integer> ints2 = gson.fromJson(json, collectionType);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON you show has a field `states`.

That field holds an array which you show as holding two *different types* of objects. One has a field `SPAWNINGPHASE`, the other a field `ALIVEPHASE`. Each of those hold an array that contains another type of object.

This poses a problem for automatic deserailization to a POJO.

The only way that could possibly work is if your `State` class had fields for every "Phase" (This is assuming you have a Java class named `NameAndDuration` that you can map those inner objects to).

```
class State {
    List<NameAndDuration> SPAWNINGPHASE;
    List<NameAndDuration> ALIVEPHASE;
    ...
}
```

Provided you mean that your `Group` class represents the JSON object, it would have:

```
List<State> states;
```

Gson silently ignores any missing fields in the JSON, so what you'd end up with is a `List` of your `State` objects, with only one of those fields set and all the others `null`.

As-is you would need to have:

```
public List<Map<String, List<NameAndDuration>>> states;
```

A JSON object is inherently a key/value map and since those objects inside the arrays are of a common type, that would work. You'd have a `List` containing `Map`s that each had one entry, the "phase" as the key and a list of those inner objects. Not exactly ideal, but it would work.

Option B and something that makes a little more sense is changing that JSON so the "phase" is a *value*:

```
{
    "states": [
        {
            "phase": "SPAWNINGPHASE",
            "values": [
                {
                    "name": "STATEA",
                    "duration": 4
                },
                {
                    "name": "STATEB",
                    "duration": 4
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And change your `State` class accordingly:

```
class State {
    String phase;
    List<NameAndDuration> values;
}
```

(Note you could also use an `enum` for `phase` here)

Now `List<State> states;` becomes a bit more usable. (Although it does seem a bit of a misnomer; it seems like you really have a list of "phases" that *contain* state info rather than a list of "states")

Comment: Thank you, that was a great explanation. Option A worked for me, but I want to try Option B. It seems that it will be a little easier to work with in the long run.